# Crash report: Enter key makes newline. How to send input?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, keyboard, crash-reports

i'm trying to send feedback on an app that crashes. I run the app, when it crashes i get a popup asking if i want to report it, which sends me to a **Feedback** form with:

- email to use
- `Write your feedback` text field
- `Include system logs` checkbox

After feedback text is typed <kbd>Enter</kbd> key just adds a newline. There's no `Send` button to click on, so it seems there's no way to proceed...

I've tried different keyboard apps, no luck with google keyboard, swiftkey or even keyboard pro which has a setting to force enter key to validate on some apps.

Using playstore 6.0.5, android 4.2.2

Comment: Based on my experience, the "Send" button should be on the bottom of the dialog/screen. Perhaps your keyboard hid the portion of the screen? Could you provide a screenshot otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, found it at last:
Turns out the "send" button is the hardly visible white triangle in the top right...

[image]